# Custom logic for BasketAddProductBehaviour app server configuration

Tags: intershop

Is there a way to add/implement custom logic for BasketAddProductBehaviour configuration value different from DisallowRepeats, MergeQuantities and AllowRepeats (https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2809G2#Concept-BasketHandlingandCheckout-Introduction)?

For example add logic that only one product from one catalog can be added to basket?

Tnx

Comment: Can you please specify for what intershop version you're asking?

Comment: Sorry, it's 7.9

Answer (score 1):

Starting with IS 7.6 add to basket functionality is implemented as chain of so called handler classes. Each handler class fulfills a particular purpose and is wired to the chain by the Java Extension Point mechanism of Intershop ICM. The com.intershop.component.basket.orm.internal.handlers.BehaviorHandler controls the add-to-basket behavior. This handler can be replaced by another implementation.